# Simple VBA: Adding Cell Address to Range with Union?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping through cells in my WS and want to add the cell address to a range (or array) as the loop finds cells which meet a criteria. I get an Object Requried error at the last line `Set`

```
Dim CellArray As Range
With ws
    With .Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total checks", .Range("A:A"), 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value,0))
        .Formula = "=SUM('" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$H:$H)"
        Set CellArray = Union(CellArray, This.Address)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CellArray` variable is not initialized. It's thus initially `Nothing`, and `Union` can't take `Nothing` as an argument.

Also, you can't access the With object (`This` does not exist), so you have to affect the Range to a variable first.

The loop body could be written (you have to declare `Dim R As Range` beforehand):

```
Set R = Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total checks", .Range("A:A"), 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value,0))

R.Formula = "=SUM('" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$H:$H)"

If CellArray Is Nothing Then
    Set CellArray = R
Else
    Set CellArray = Union(CellArray, R)
End If
```

Comment: I am getting Variable not defined at `This`

Comment: @SeanKelly I didn't check that in your code. It's fixed.

Comment: I have 41 identical lines of code, each referencing different Totals i need to match. Is there any way to do this without declaring 41 different range variables in addition to `R`? This is also the reason i am using a `With` statement

Comment: @SeanKelly Maybe you could use the same variable for all. That depends on your code, but since you don't use the Range outside With anyway, it should be safe to reassign R to something else. You could update your question to show a few more lines, just to check.

Comment: Thanks for your help cub. This is almost working, but `Set CellArray = R` and then `Set CellArray = Union(CellArray, R)` returns the value inside the cell. I am looking to build an array of cell addresses so that i can loop through them later in the program.  `Set CellArray = R.Address` does not work and returns Type Mismatch

Comment: @SeanKelly R.Address is a String, so you can't use the Set syntax with it (it's for objects). R is not the value of the cell, but a Range. You may check this by putting `Debug.Print TypeName(R)` just after the assignment. Maybe you should also check that the arguments of Cells return a valid result. For integers I and J, `Cells(I, J)` is a Range with only one cell (at row I and column J). `Cells(I, J).Value` is its value.

Comment: Working. Thanks cub!

Answer (score 0):

try this

please do not use "With" command because it makes code hard to read in most situations (like yours)

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet            ' or point to any worksheet here, if you want  

    Dim CellArray As Range

    Dim myCell As Range             ' range("a:a") must contain "Total checks", otherwise next line will fail
    Set myCell = ws.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total checks", ws.Range("A:A"), 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value, 0))

    myCell.Select                   ' debug ... visually verify the cell location

    myCell.Formula = "=SUM('" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$H:$H)"

    If CellArray Is Nothing Then
        Set CellArray = myCell      ' CellArray cannot be empty to start, otherwise the "union" function will fail
    Else
        Set CellArray = Union(CellArray, myCell)
    End If

    CellArray.Select                ' debug ... visually verify the resulting CellArray range

End Sub
```