# Macro Runtime Suddenly Slow

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization

I have an identical piece of code which was running nearly instantly in an previous iteration which now takes about 5 minutes to run. I edited other parts of the code, but whenever I break the code within that 5 minute period of time, it is working through this sub.

```
Sub cleanup()

For i = 2 To 100000

'exits loop when it reaches a blank cell
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) = True Then Exit For

' formats for blanks
If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
    For j = 4 To 15
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i - 1, j)) = True Then
        Cells(i - 1, j) = Cells(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
    Rows(i).Delete
    i = i - 1
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I've tried disabling events and screen updating etc, but can't figure it out. Keep in mind this used to run literally instantly and I only changed other functions in my code since those changes. Not sure what to do. 
Thanks!

**

The other part which is very weird is when I run the macro again (after all the rows are deleted) it still takes a very long time. In the above macro, the second time through it should never even enter the first conditional but it still takes a long time.

**

Comment: Do you need to loop `i` all the way to `100000`? It might speed things up to simply loop to the last row of the used range

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad His first line should exit the loop at the first blank

Comment: @dwirony quite right, I missed that.

Comment: Kind of a tangent, but if you’re deleting rows in a loop, you should do it in reverse order so that it doesn’t skip rows

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 or, build a `Union` range as you go, and only run 1 single `Range.Delete` operation =)

Comment: Could it be that a lot of your cells now have `” “` instead of being actually blank, causing this to loop a boat load?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon nah, that’d be the easy way. I want make sure computer *works hard* every day so I know it can get stronger!

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Can you elaborate on how building a range using union would work in a loop like this?

Comment: @Hunter B - See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109900/simple-vba-adding-cell-address-to-range-with-union#45110144) for adding cells to a range union. You could also use `If IsEmpty(Cells(i - 1, j)) Then` as `IsEmpty(Cells(i - 1, j))` will return either true or false already.

Comment: Ooh another note, I see you tried to counteract the point I mentioned about it skipping lines by writing `i = i - 1` BUT vba is a fickle mistress and does not let you manually update the value of `i` while the loop is running

Comment: Does the "etc" include `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`?  Do you have any other workbooks open now that weren't open when it was running instantly?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub cleanup()

For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + To 2 step -1

    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        For j = 4 To 15
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i - 1, j)) Then Cells(i - 1, j) = Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        If CellArray Is Nothing Then
            Set CellArray = Rows(i)
        Else
            Set CellArray = Union(CellArray, Rows(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

CellArray.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this piece of code after adding declarations and fixing the syntax of the for loop line. It sped up the runtime from about 5 minutes to about 4. Which is great! Thank you!    But I'm still so confused why this code would run instantly before and still take 4 minutes with optimization   :/

Comment: The other part which is very weird is when I run the macro again (after all the rows are deleted) it still takes a very long time. In the above macro, the second time through it should never even enter the first conditional but it still takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I may be oversimplifying your task, but if you use the built-in `counta` function within Excel, I think it would be very efficient at determining if a row had values in it or not:

```
If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rw.EntireRow) = 0 Then
  rw.Delete
End If
```

Of course, this looks at the entire row and you probably want to bound that to columns 4 - 15 (or whatever you showed above).

Also, I think @Marcucciboy2 made a good point, and I would start from the bottom up.

If you really wanted to make this hum, you could probably define these in a range context (ie 1:4,5:7 etc) and delete the entire collection of rows at one time.

Answer (score 0):

In the excel, if you can avoid the for loops, its very slow. For example: my work i use 7000x746x3 rows, and its running about 15 minutes(i5 7300u,but not mucher faster on desktop 7770. Maybe little optimazition here: https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm or use foreach. And if you use for you can count the row/column. Example row count:

```
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```